# new to java and I'm having a file that has classes and a fileTest to acess those classes

Tags: java, class

I have a class file consists of other classes then I have another file to test my code both are in eclipse what do I need to include in my testfile to be able to access and test the classes in my class file

for example the class file has

```
public class myFile {

    public class MyClass1 {
    }

    public class MyClass2{
   } 
}// end myFile class
```

my test file has

```
public class myTestFile{
     public static void main (String[] args){
<WHAT DO I DECLARE HERE to access Myclass1 and Myclass2 ????

    }

}
```

Comment: Are `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` really declared inside a class called `myFile`? because you probably don't need to do that

Comment: Note that, in Java, each top-level class has to be in its own file. If you declare your classes `MyClass1`, and `MyClass2` the way you do, they are members of class `myFile` and can only be instantiated together with `myFile`. Also, for testing (that is, if you fancy unit-testing), you probably want to look at JUnit, which is the standard for testing Java. Your test-classes can call the classes from your production code just like any production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the inner classes are accessed by creating an object of the outer class type and then invoking the constructors of the inner classes on it:

```
class Outer {

    public class Inner {

    }
}

static void test() {
    Outer outer = new Outer();
    Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
}
```

If the inner class is declared with `static` keyword, no object of outer type is required and you can simply instantiate the object of inner class type by invoking

```
Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();
```

I'm not sure about it right now, but I suspect that the inner class should have a public constructor to enable object creation outside of the outer class.

Comment: @ParthaBenjapi It did it, but please do think through whether this is what you actually want. Inner classes are relatively advanced ideas; if you're new to Java, you really don't want to be doing this, even if you've now got the right syntax to get it to work.

Comment: I agree. Use inner classes only to distill and encapsulate some specific functionality of the outer class and only if you need access to the inner fields or methods of the outer class; otherwise it's often wiser to think about redesigning your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same package you just need to create an instance of Class1 or Class2 like this :

```
Class1 myObject1 = new Class1();
Class12 myObject2 = new Class2();
```

If you are not in the same package (means that the `package your_package;` on top of the files are different just import the other class with `import anotherpackage.Class1;` or `import anotherpackage.Class2;`

Comment: I tried that but it says it can't be resolved to a type

Comment: Are all your classes in the same package ?

Comment: you need to add the import and package used at the begining of each file so I can help you because I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: @ParthaBenjapi It's because `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are inner classes of class `myFile`, which complicates things, and probably unnecessarily. I've added an answer of my own that deals with this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the entire contents of those files? If so, you might notice that Eclipse gives a warning that you're saving these classes in the *default package*, which is not encouraged. You should Edit / Refactor in Eclipse, and then move the classes to a new package, like

```
com.benjapi.myclass
```

or similar. Ideally the test one would go in

```
com.benjapi.myclass.test
```

Once you've done this, and you've put the two classes into sensible packages, you can think about how to reference classes from one file in the other file.

The next thing you need to do, by the look of it, is move `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` into separate files. At the moment, they're *inner classes* of class `myFile`, and I'm pretty sure this isn't what you meant. Bin the `myFile` class, and have `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` as separate classes.

Then, if they're in the same package, you don't need anything too clever at all, but just

```
MyClass1 thing = new MyClass1();
```

will be enough to get you a new `MyClass1` instance. If they're in different packages, though, then you need to add an `import` line at the top of your test class (just underneath the `package` line that Eclipse will add for you when you move it to a new package):

```
import com.benjapi.myclass.myFile;
```

Then you can just use

```
MyClass1 thing = new MyClass1();
```

as before. In fact, Eclipse helps you with this too: even before you've added the `import` line, if you try to use `MyClass1`, then Eclipse will give you a warning (a little red cross with a yellow lightbulb on it in the left-hand margin). You can right-click it and then add the import, or even just Ctrl-Shift-O to organize imports and add the necessary `import` lines automatically.